# Sorting the last column in array of strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, structure

I have a .txt file that contains the following:

```
1    - Ground   2
2    - Ground   7
3    - City     1
4    - Hill     x
5    - City     3
6    - City     4
7    - Hill     6
```

The task is to sort these game slots in a particular order: the *first* column of the file is the *slot number*, the *second* column of the file is the *slot type*, and the *third* column of the file is the *number of the slot that is on the right of the slot in question*.

The `x` means that no slot is on the right of that slot so that would mean that slot 4 (Hill) is the last slot in the ordered slots. So the program must search through the text file to find the `x` then see what the slot number is on that line to see what slot is to the left of that. After it has completed this it should output the following:

```
(5,City)->(3, City)->(1, Ground)->(2,Ground)->(7,Hill)->(6,City)->(4,Hill)
```

## This is my code so far:

This code reads in the text file and prints the initial list of slots. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const char *SLOTS_FILE_PATH = "slots.txt";

char slotsArr[7][100];
char newSlots[7][100];

int main()
{
     int i = 0;
     int j;
     char search;

     FILE *fx = fopen(SLOTS_FILE_PATH, "r+");   

         if (fx == NULL)
         {
            perror("Error opening slots file");
            i = -1;
         }
         else
         {
             while(fgets(slotsArr[i],
             sizeof(slotsArr[i]), fx) != NULL)
         {
             i++;
         }

             fclose (fx);
         }

     printf("\n-------Initial List of Slots-------\n");

     for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
     {
         printf("%s", slotsArr[j]);
     }

     printf("\n-------Sorted List of Slots-------\n");

     }
```

*********************And this is what it outputs*************************

```
 -------Initial List of Slots-------
 1  - Ground    2
 2  - Ground    7
 3  - City      1
 4  - Hill      x
 5  - City      3
 6  - City      4
 7  - Hill      6

 -------Sorted List of Slots-------
```

Comment: You need a structure, properly reading the data into the structure, `qsort()` and the appropriate comparison functions.

Comment: Do you realise that your data is actually a (set of) linked list(s) ? (or a D(A)G, or a tree ...)

Comment: Have you learned about `struct` types yet?  You should almost certainly be using one for this exercise.

Comment: No we haven't covered structs yet, the idea is to search the array for the x and then work backwards comparing arrays and swapping elements till you get back to the start.

Comment: OK.  Even without structures, you need to make some progress.  For example, you need two parallel arrays, one for the names, one for the successor numbers.  You'll populate those by appropriate reading operations (I'd probably go with `fgets()` to read lines and `sscanf()` to parse the lines).  You can then tell what to do.  Note that you'll need to allow for the `x` entry.

Comment: Why does he need to arrays, @JonathanLeffler?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad: He could use 3 if he wanted to. There are two columns of key relevance — the name and the link (last). The first column is basically just an index into the array. I'd probably simply allocate enough space that I could ignore the zeroth element of the arrays, using the numbers as specified in the file. There may be other ways to do it — but it seems silly from where I'm sitting to read the 4 columns (I know the question says 3, but the dashes look like a column to me, albeit boring and not worth storing) into strings and then spend the whole time manipulating long strings. YMMV!

Comment: There is no need for more than on array. The list is well-formatted. And there is nothing to manipulate. He has to partially copy the items to the results – what he would do, creating more than one array.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad: Fine — do it your way; I'm only making suggestions that I think will help. You may make suggestions too, perhaps even an answer, and you can do it your way. If I had my druthers, I'd be using a structure, but the OP hasn't learned about them yet. A lot depends on the diversity of inputs you expect to manage with your code. If the numbers go above 9, or the names get to be longer than 9 characters, then things using a single array gets harder. Also, since the required output is the leading number and the name only, you've got to extract the name from the long line. Up to you.

Comment: If the structure of the list becomes more complex, copying columns of the list into separate arrays become harder, too. Indeed, a structure would be the right thing to handle that. He cannot do that. But it is still a list of items, organized in rows. To separate them columnwise into arrays does not lead to the solution. It is simply the feeling that you want to have more structure in the data.

Answer (score 0):

Typed that in my browser, so there will be typos. (I have a bandage at one hand …) However, a pointer:

```
char slotsArr[7][100];
char newSlots[7][100];
…

// It starts with x
char charToSearch = 'x'; // It doesn't matter, whether it is a digit or char. 
int sortedIndex = 7; // Start at the right side.
while( sortedIndex>0 )
{
  // search for the row by iterating over the array and comparing the last letter.
  for( int unsortedIndex=6; unsortedIndex>=0; unsortedIndex-- )
  {
    if( charToSearch == slotsArr[unsortedIndex][16] )
    {
      charToSearch = slotsArr[unsortedIndex][0]; // The next item's index
      sortedIndex--;
      // The format of the result array is not clear in your Q. 
      // However, this is not the problem. I put a number and the trimmed 
      // string into it. You can add the parenthesis and the - at output, 
      // if you want to.
      newSlots[sortedIndex][0]=charToSearch;
      newSlots[sortedIndex][1]=',';

      // Copy the string up to a space
      char src = slotsArray[unsortedIndex]+7;
      char *dest = newSlots[sortedIndex]+2;
      while( !isspace(src) )
      {
        *dst++ = *src++;
      }
      *dst='\0';
      break;
    }
  }
}
```